# Эксперименты со строками

Tags: алгоритм

Дано: среда программирования ‘A’, которая поддерживает все стандартные процедуры над строками (копировать, удалить, вставить, найти и прочее). ‘A’ также позволяет записывать строки в файл. Но у ‘A’ есть один большой минус – он может работать только со строками очень ограниченной длины N.

Задача: записать в файл строку длины M, пользуясь средой программирования ‘A’. M>>N, и мы перезаписываем строку из одного файла в другой.

Мне интересно возможно ли это в принципе, и если да, то в какую сторону копать?

Comment: А считывать строки по N символов и записывать их в файл, пока не перепишем все M символов чем не устраивает?

Comment: В смысле записывать в файл строку длины M построчно строками длины N? Хорошо, тогда КАК мы считаем (N+1)-ый символ строки длины M (из файла)?

Хм, хотя наверное можно, если удалять то, что мы считали. Ладно, протестирую в старом добром Паскале, посмотрим, что из этого получится

Comment: Условие некорректно, не сказано явно, что среда не поддерживает Append файла. Соответственно, конкатенацию строк можно проводить прямо в файле. Такое же замечание насчет чтения.

Comment: Хорошо, но даже с Append каши не сваришь - он дописывает, но не перезаписывает.
Переформулирую вопрос: есть сабы к фильму со сбитым временем появления. И есть программист, которой хочет написать прогу (причём непременно на Паскале), которая бы меняла это время (несколько символов в начале каждой строки) на заданное кол-во секунд. Когда я ещё учился в школе, я реализовывал это с помощью перезаписи из одного файла в другой, ну и менял в строках то, что мне нужно. Но иногда строки "не влезали". И сейчас меня интересует можно ли средствами Паскаль сделать то, что я тогда так и недоделал

Comment: @Bran, отредактируйте вопрос. А еще лучше, задайте новый вопрос с конкретной прикладной задачей (не забудьте указать, что Паскаль имеется ввиду TP с его характерными строками) и я попробую ответить. Здесь же приводится задача с ограничениями для чисто академического интереса.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда так и поступлю

Comment: по первых если у вас жесткая привязка к длинее обрабатываемой строки, то уже накладывается ограничение на M и N. M должно быть кратно N, иначе работать не будет. с другой стороны язык непомешало бы указать :)

Comment: @jmu, обсуждение продолжилось здесь: http://hashcode.ru/questions/110081/

По поводу того, что M должно быть кратно N - не вижу смысла. Eoln и eof ещё никто не отменял

Comment: мне показалось что условие что строка заданной длинны распостраняется на все функции в том числе и считывание из файла/запись в файл. посему трудно было представить как такие функции будут обрабатывать "остаток" символов в файле